Проблема принятия ботом сообщений
Всем привет. Только начал изучать разработку ботов на питоне и встретился с проблемой. Сначала бот выдавал при запуске на стадии тестирования ошибку "Error. Try again later". Я специально добавил, чтобы бот хоть что-то присылал. Он перестал давать эту ошибку. После чего я решил немного заспамить бота сообщениями /start, чтобы проверить, что с ним будет. Как итог, я не могу отправлять боту сообщения /start. Они просто уходят в бесконечную отправку в самом тг. При чём поменял
message_hendler(['start'])

на
message_handler(content_types=["text'])

он стал работать и реагировать на все сообщения. Но /start так же не отправляется. Сталкивался ли кто-то с такой проблемой и если да, то как её решал. Так же буду благодарен советам по самому коду.
Ниже прикладываю код программы.
import telebot
from telebot.types import *
import texts

bot = telebot.TeleBot('Token')
users_dict = {}
order_dict = {}


@bot.message_handler(['start'])
def start(msg: Message):
    global users_dict
    print(msg.chat.id)
    if msg.chat.id not in list(users_dict.keys()):
        users_dict[msg.chat.id] = {}
        bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, texts.first_text % msg.from_user.first_name)
        order(msg)
        return
    else:
        order(msg)
        return


def order(msg: Message):

    kb = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
    kb.row("Пиво, сидры и снэки", "Кальяны", "Чай")
    kb.row("Лимонады, соки и вода", "Кофе и молочные коктейли")
    kb.row('Оформление заказа')
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Для совершения заказа выберите интересующий вас раздел:', reply_markup=kb)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, menu_sender)
    return


def menu_sender(msg: Message):
    tag = msg.text
    if tag == 'Пиво, сидры и снэки':
        bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, texts.beers)
        menu_1(msg)
    elif tag == '2':
        menu_2(msg)
    elif tag == '3':
        menu_3(msg)
    elif tag == '4':
        menu_4(msg)
    elif tag == '5':
        menu_5(msg)
    elif tag == 'Оформление заказа':
        order_pay_check(msg)
    else:
        bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Error, try again later')
        print(users_dict)


def menu_1(msg: Message):
    kb1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=False)
    for i in list(texts.beers_dict.keys()):
        kb1.row(i)
    kb1.row("Назад")
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Выберите позицию, которую хотите добавить в ваш заказ.', reply_markup=kb1)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, menu_1_checker)


def menu_1_checker(msg: Message):
    global users_dict
    if msg.text == 'Назад':
        order(msg)
    else:
        bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, f'В ваш заказ добавлено: {msg.text}')
        users_dict[msg.chat.id][msg.text] = texts.beers_dict[msg.text]
        print(users_dict)
        menu_1(msg)


def menu_2(msg: Message):
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Здесь будет раздел 2')


def menu_3(msg: Message):
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Здесь будет раздел 3')


def menu_4(msg: Message):
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Здесь будет раздел 4')


def menu_5(msg: Message):
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Здесь будет раздел 5')


def order_pay_check(msg: Message):
    global order_dict
    order_dict[msg.chat.id] = [sum([i for i in list(users_dict[msg.chat.id].values())]),
                               'Ваш заказ:\n']
    for i in list(users_dict[msg.chat.id].keys()):
        order_dict[msg.chat.id][1] += f'{i} - {users_dict[msg.chat.id][i]}\n'
    print(order_dict)
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, order_dict[msg.chat.id][1] + f'\nИтого: {order_dict[msg.chat.id][0]} руб.')


bot.infinity_polling()


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Хай, давай разберёмся, как ты умудрился испортить себе жизнь.
Где ты налажал: Ты использовал @bot.message_handler(['start']) вместо правильного @bot.message_handler(commands=['start']). В результате бот начал воспринимать /start как обычный текст, а не как команду. Это привело к бесконечной петле сообщений.
Поправь декоратор на правильный:
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(msg: Message):
   # твой код тута

А вообще прежде чем делать тг бота почитай хотя бы документацию и посмотри туториалы в инете.
Вот пару линков тебе:
Дударь
Документация
Рекомендую забить на telebot и сразу использовать aiogram
